# Using sed to match anything and \s

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I've got the following:

```
sed -i "s/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"100/s\"/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"10\s\"/g"
```

Question is how do I avoid this error?

```
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'
```

And is there a way to do a wild card match and replace with sed?

Comment: Better to put input file (or string) and expected **output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many slashes, 4 when there should be 3.  Use a different delimiter; *comma* (,),  *bang* (!), *hash* (#), and *at* (@) are common alternatives.

`sed -i "s,SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"100/s\",SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"10\s\",g"`

Note that you have "100/s" in the original and "10s" (no slash) in the replacement.  To actually insert a *backslash*, you'd need to enter 4 of them: `10\\\\s`.  Each pair will get reduced to a single by the shell and then the remaining double will be interpreted as a literal backslash by `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first `grep` then substitute :

```
sed -i '/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"100/s/"\/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = \"10\s\"/replacement/g'
```

But the delimiter can be anything else than `/`, see :

```
sed -i '/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = "100/s@"/SYNFLOOD_RATE  = "10\s"@replacement@g'
```

( the delimiter here is `@`)